# Minipages and spacing between \paragraph

Tags: spacing, minipage, sections-paragraphs

I am using \paragraph inside a minipage. Don't know why, but the usual space above \paragraph does not appear. Then I have a small minipage in the \paragraph. Now spacing between \paragraph is increased (maybe back to normal). Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? I would like \paragraph to behave the same as outside the minipage (no vertical space if at the top of the page, slightly elastic vertical space thereafter, don't need numbering).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.9\linewidth}
\paragraph{A} Blah 
\paragraph{B} Blah 
\paragraph{C} Blah 
\newline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
BLAH BLAH
\end{minipage}
\newline
More blah 
\paragraph{D} Blah 
\paragraph{E} Blah 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are probably misusing `\paragraph` ;). Why do you want to use it here? It does not seem appropriate to start new sections within a `minipage`. `\paragraph{}` is for starting a new section, a sub-division of a sub-sub-section. It is not for starting a new paragraph. It just has a confusing name. To start a new paragraph, leave a blank line. (Or use `\par` but a blank line is better in most places.)

Comment: I am using the minipage to get a bit of text of less width than the rest of the document, and I wanted the same sectioning and formatting within the minipage as elsewhere.

Comment: You want 5 sectional divisions on a single page?

Comment: `\newline` is (almost) always wrong, and probably not what you want. You are getting the same formatting, by the way. A `minipage` is a small page so, just like for a regular page, vertical space is not needed at the top. But by the time you've given each `\paragraph` its title, is there much space left to say anything in each section?

Comment: I made a simple example showing the problem I have encountered. There is no spaces between \paragraphs at first, and after the second minipage somehow there is a persistent space before each \paragraph. Doesn't seem logical to me.

Comment: Just checked, \newline doesn't make any difference for the vertical spacing. It is the second minipage that changes things.

Comment: I'm just saying that it isn't really surprising that sectional commands don't work predictably when used in ways they aren't designed to be used. That's all. I think a different approach would work better.

Comment: Recommend you go read the documentation for the `quoting` package, especially the options on pages 2-3. http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/quoting/quoting.pdf  This gives you an environment where you specify the new left and right margins for the text in the environment.  And this plays nicely with normal LaTeX layout.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `\mbox{}` in the beging of the `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
\mbox{}
\paragraph{A} Blah 
\paragraph{B} Blah 
\paragraph{C} Blah 
\newline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
BLAH BLAH
\end{minipage}
\newline
More blah 
\paragraph{D} Blah 
\paragraph{E} Blah 
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

An other solution is `\parbox`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\parbox[t]{0.9\linewidth}{
\paragraph{A} Blah 
\paragraph{B} Blah 
\paragraph{C} Blah 
\newline
\parbox[t]{0.5\linewidth}{
BLAH BLAH
}
\newline
More blah 
\paragraph{D} Blah 
\paragraph{E} Blah 
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want a bit of text with less width than the rest of the document. If that's all you want, I'd suggest you try the `addmargin` environment:

```
\begin{addmargin}[4em]{1em}
foo bar
\end{addmargin}
```

Usage is `\begin{addmargin}[<left indentation>]{<indentation>}`. There is a starred variant `addmargin*` where the optional parameter stands for the *inner* margin.

In order to use this environment, you must either use one of the KOMA script classes (`texdoc scrguien`) or `\usepackage{scrextend}`.

According to the KOMA user manual:

> Similar to quote and quotation, the addmargin environment changes the margin. In contrast to the first two environments, with addmargin the user can set the width of the indentation. Besides this, this environment does not change the indentation of the first line nor the vertical spacing between paragraphs.

(see page 112)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{addmargin}{3cm}
   \lipsum[2]
\end{addmargin}

\begin{addmargin}[2cm]{3cm}
   \lipsum[3]
\end{addmargin}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I actually want to put stuff in that extra "margin". I suppose what I am trying to do is more of simple a multi-column environment with the main text in one column, and perhaps a list in another and/or a graphic in the third.

Comment: You might have said that before.... :) How much "stuff" do you want to put there? Is it more like a `marginpar` (some keywords and/or symbols) or more like a multi-column environment? Is the "stuff" linked to the main text and, if so, how tightly?

Comment: Thanks again. More like a multi-column environment, with no linking between columns. Similar to Beamer's columns environment, but should work in the article class. My starting point is two minipages side by side.

Comment: What about `\usepackage{parcolumns}` ? It has some limitations, but might get the job done. However, quick testing showed me that the use of `\colchunk` (in order to change the column deliberately), also changes the vertical spacing between `paragraph`s.